# why isn't python getattr raising an AttributeError while being ran in celery?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code that looks like:

```
try:
    my_var = getattr(SOME_OBJECT, 'some_field_inside')
except AttributeError:
    # do some stuff
```

I expect the code to behave in a way, where the `some_filed_inside` is present in `SOME_OBJECT`, I get it, otherwise, since there is no default value, it would raise an `AttributeError`. what I actually get is, unfortunately, `my_var = None`

this isn't the case in my test cases, or local tests that I run, but same code when being ran by `celery`, stops raising the error.

I tried adding loggs to see whats being set to `my_var` in the celery app, and I can confirm it's being set to `None`. but somehow, the exception isn't being raised. my solution for now looks like following. because I can predict if the same code would magically start to raise error instead of setting the value to `None`:

```
try:
    my_var = getattr(SOME_OBJECT, 'some_field_inside')
    if not my_var:
        raise AttributeError("some message")
except AttributeError:
    # do some stuff
```

I am using python3.8 and python3.9 for this testing. and celery 4.4.2